# CMOS battery issue

Tags: battery, desktop-computer, cmos

The 5+ year old CMOS battery in my PC died and the BIOS lost it's settings.  I replaced the battery but the same problem persists.

As soon as I plug the PC into the power outlet, I get 4 beeps (accompanied with flashing red LED).  After a few minutes, I manage to boot up the PC, set up the BIOS, and load everything. Then it operates normally.

The issue happens again after I fully shut down the PC (even without unplugging it from the power outlet).

Any ideas what might be causing this problem ?

I tried a good working battery from the other PC but the same thing happens (this eliminates the battery as the cause).

Comment: Did you do a CMOS reset after replacing?
Just check the beep code for your system, as it tells you what is wrong.

Comment: [beep codes](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm)

Comment: Some of the battery slots are so poorly made when you insert the battery , it has bent it a little and the metal connections in the battery slot are not connecing. Some batteries are so badly made :-) you should test them before inserting. Check also the Cmos Jumper is where it is supposed to be. wrong placement of the jumper usually would also cause other weirdness, but one thing it will do is keep it cleared. If the battery was put in upside down, it may fit like that , observing how the 2 connections are made to the battery before placement, would be the way to figure it out.

Comment: At the end - motherboard was the culprit. After replacing it, problems went away.